# Uniquely Satisfying Puzzle

Tags: problems

Here is a fun puzzle I found some time ago. It was created by Karl Fabel in 1952 and published in Rätselstunde.

## Goal

```
[title "White to move and NOT checkmate in one!"]
[fen "B5KR/1r5B/6R1/2b1p1p1/2P1k1P1/1p2P2p/1P2P2P/3N1N2 w - - 0 1"]
```

This is honestly one of the most unique puzzles I ever saw.

It will take some time to find the solution but it is very satisfying once you do.

> Hopefully there is a way to post a comment with your guesses without spoiling the fun for others. Please use `>!` to hide your post and prevent spoilers.

Comment: This problem was composed by Karl Fabel and published in Rätselstunde in 1952. The original version also had black knights on c8 and e8 but these are often omitted when this charming problem is reproduced.

Comment: I don't know others but took me 30 seconds to solve.

Comment: This problem is published on an interactive chessboard https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=2079&lang=en#1

Comment: @DrCapablasker  the link does not go to the puzzle nor solution although there is a starting position chessboard shown.

Comment: Well resign would avoid it.   I hope that is not the solution. White cannot move any piece legally without causing mate unless that position is really bizarre and the board is upside down with white at the top and then p-q8=n  [d8=N]   is the answer.

Comment: There is a valid solution that involves making a move. There are no “tricks” like you mentioned here.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is a duplicate on another site (my question) https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52154/a-very-unique-chess-puzzle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Cute puzzle. Rc6 solves it. :)

[image]

Comment: Please use `>!` to hide your answer so it doesn't spoil it for other users :)

Comment: Wow, that was cool ">!". I learned something there.

Comment: To the down-voter: You have to hover over, or tap on, the answer to see it.

Comment: Rc6 does not solve it as moving that rook causes mate instantly and NO the black rook cann NOT take the white bishop as black is already mated.

Comment: Rc6 absolutely is not mate in one. Rc6 Rxh7, and black is not mated...yet. P.S. I plugged this into a computer just to make sure that I was correct, and I am.

Comment: I plead senior moment.  You are right.

Comment: Thank you. No problem.

Answer (score 3):

> The only pieces white can move are the two knights, one of its rooks, and one of its bishops. None of the pieces can move without giving check. The black King cannot move to avoid that check, so the checking piece must be captured. That leaves only the rook as an option. If the rook moves it exposes a bishop to give check. The bishop is attacked by a black rook which is pinned. Thus the white rook must move to unpin the black rook.